# Is there any array helper online software?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to work with huge arrays sometimes. I mean really long nested arrays in PHP and when I `print_r` them you don't have a chance to understand anything it's so much, then I use `print_r` in between HTML `<pre></pre>` which makes it a bit better.

I'm searching for an online array helper where I copy the array, put it in and then can see how to access a certain value. It's just hard to try to figure out, hey I need to do: `$array[0][test][4][value]`

Is there a tool which helps to find what I'm looking for in an array and how to access it?

Comment: I don't know which IDE you use, but in PHP Storm you can easly use xdebug to read out data. I'm not sure but I think xdebug can also be a good use in other IDE's

Comment: phillihp.com may satisfy you. There are tons of tool online that can help you with that. Anyway, you can debug an array with PHP `dd($your_array)`, it definitely helps

Comment: You can also use [Kint](https://github.com/kint-php/kint)

Comment: `It's just hard to try to figure out`...not when the structure is printed clearly, it's not. print_r, var_dump and var_export all provide adequate output for that purpose. It's just a hierarchical structure. Follow the array elements down the tree, then list them in your command in the order of the hierarchy. Take a tutorial and do some practice: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-multidimensional-array/

Answer (score 1):

A way is to output your huge array as a JSON with `echo json_encode($array);`.

You can put the output then in some kind of JSON inspector tool. I use [JsonFormatter by Curiousconcept](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), or just inspect the raw output from the URL it's outputted on with this [JSONVue plugin for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonvue/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)

If you use any good IDE (like VSCode or PHPStorm) you can add the contents to a .json file and let your IDE format the file, after which you get folding icons in the gutter.